# Is it possible to delete the embed if it has a certain word after its edited

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

> **in this form if possible**

```
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  const words = ['word1', 'word2']

  });
```

Tried using  ***embed.title.includes('word')*** but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an embed in a message, you can get the embeds' data through [`message.embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds). This return an array of [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed) in the message if exist or null if there is no embed. Now you just check each the embed, parse it to JSON and get its properties([`embed.title`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=title), [`embed.description`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=description), etc...).
Here is an example of getting embeds' data:

```js
const embeds = message.embeds?.map(embed => embed?.toJSON()); // Get array of message embeds parsed to JSON
if (!embeds) return; // Return if no embed in the message
let include = false; // Define the variable to check in each embed
for(let i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) { // Loop through the embeds gotten from message
    const embed = embeds[i];
    // The variables below are the embed's part which can contain string
    const title = embed.title;
    const description = embed.description;
    const footer = embed.footer?.text; // footer maybe null, put ? after footer won't throw error "Can not read property of null (reading 'text')"
    if (title?.includes('word') || description?.includes('word') || footer?.includes('word')) { // Check if the embed contains 'word' or not
        include = true; // The embed contains the word, so set `include` to true
        break; // We now have what we need, destroy the loop
    }
}
if (include) console.log('The message embeds contain the `word` word!');
else { console.log('The message embeds don\'t contain the `word` word.'); }
```

Comment: Thank you! but how do i make it so it does that on when an embed is also getting edited? cause if i use client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) it won't work.

Comment: the `message` object in my code is [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message) class, is the same with `newMessage` object in your code. So you just replace `message` with `newMessage`.

Comment: @AnyBananaGAME if it fixed your problem give the answer a check mark !

Comment: oh ty ty did not even see the checkmark!